Zariski topology on $\text{Max}(C(X, \mathbb R))$
Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and let $C(X)$ be the ring of continuous functions $X\rightarrow\mathbb R$. The maximal ideals $\text{Max}(C(X))$ correspond simply to points of $X$ in the usual way (as functions that are zero at $p$).
Now let's take the Zariski topology on $\text{Max}(C(X))\cong X$ (as sets). My question is: how does it relate to the original topology on $X$?
Since for any $f\in C(X)$ the set $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed in the original topology (as a preimage of a closed set), and a general Zariski-closed set is an intersection of such sets, we have that any Zariski-closed set is closed in the original topology.
To go in the other direction, we'd have to construct a function $f$ which is zero precisely on a chosen set $Y\subset X $ closed in the original topology. I believe we can do that for metric spaces, by taking $f(p) = \text{dist}(P,X)$ to be the distance function, but I'm not sure about general $X$.


To go in the other direction, we'd have to construct a function $f$ which is zero precisely on a chosen set $Y⊂X$ closed in the original topology.

Luckily you don't. In fact I don't think you can do this for general $X$ though I don't have a counterexample. In the Zariski topology closed sets are the vanishing sets of ideals, so we only need to find an ideal whose vanishing set is $Y.$
If some set of functions $f_i$ generate an ideal $I$ then the vanishing set of $I$ is the intersection of the vanishing set of the $f_i.$ Therefore it is sufficient to find an $f_x$ for each $x\not\in Y$ such that $f_x$ vanishes on $Y$ but not on $x.$
We can do this because a compact Hausdorff space is normal, so we can use Urysohn's metrization lemma for the closed sets $Y$ and $\{x\}$ to get such a function.

Ah, it seems that Urysohn's lemma is exactly what I've been missing, thanks! To be clear: in this case the Zariski topology coincides with the original topology on $X$?

@lisyarus Yes, the closed sets are the same for both topologies (you had the other direction) and hence so are the open sets.

I see, thank you!

Zsombor Kiss explained quite well that if $X$ is compact Hausdorff, then Zariski topology does coincide with the given topology of $X$, but I think there are a few more interesting things to be said here.
A set of zeroes of a continuous function is often called a zero set. It is easy to see that it is always a closed $G_\delta$ set, and spaces for which all closed sets are zero sets are called perfectly normal, and they are exactly the spaces where all closed sets are $G_\delta$.
A counterexample is $\omega_1+1$: the point $\{\omega_1\}$ is closed, but not $G_\delta$, and one can show directly that every continuous function $f\colon \omega_1+1\to \mathbf R$ has to be eventually constant.
Now if $X$ is not compact Hausdorff, then you can still consider the space of maximal ideals of $C_b(X)$ (bounded continuous real-valued functions) with the Zariski topology. It is always a compact Hausdorff space, and one can check that it is in fact $\beta X$, the Čech-Stone (universal) $T_2$ compactification of $X$. If $X$ is completely regular, then it forms its subspace.
